# How to utilize Global Variables with Newman in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, automated-tests, postman, newman

Background: Our application has an API that pulls out specific work orders from the database (GET) and a POST requests which retrieves all the information related to that work order to display on the portal.

Problem: I am trying to GET that workorder Id and post it into a Global Variable, which is then accessed in another API call in the body. I can get this to work just fine in the Postman App, but I cannot figure out how to get it to work in Azure using newman

All the files live in an Azure repo, and I can get it all to work with environment files, etc. I could just specify a global file, but the Data (workOrderId) within that file will change with every run (the workOrderId will not always be the same)

What I have tried:
I have tried including the -g globals.json and --export-globals globals.json command, but it gave an empty file error.

I tried creating a separate Get-Globals task to simply export the global, THEN run the command to run the collection, but that did not seem to work either.

My concerns are whether pipelines has access to write to files in an Azure repo? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Which Azure service do you use to run Newman?

Comment: I am using Azure Pipelines.